# PHP Script Keep Adding the Same ID to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm trying to add new temporary transaction data to MySQL using this PHP script below.

```
if ($mod == "penjualan" AND $act == "add") {
    //check data from table barang detail where id from the form 
    $cekBarang = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbbarangdetail
                            WHERE idBarangDetail = '$_GET[id]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cekBarang);

    if ($assoc != NULL) {
        $disc = 0;
        //check discount
        if(!empty($_GET['disc']) AND is_numeric($_GET['disc'])) {
            $disc = $_GET['disc'];
        }
        //get hargaPerKg and hargaPerBarang
        $a = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT hargaPerKg, hargaPerBarang FROM tbbarang where idBarang = '$assoc[idBarang]'");
        $b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a);
        //get jumlah Kg from detail barang
        $jumlahKg = $assoc['jumlahKg'];
        //set id transaksi detail automatically
        $idTransaksiDetailtmp = noTransaksiDetail();
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $tgl = date('Y-m-d');
        $timestmp = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        //check data from table transaksi detail tmp
        $cekDetBarang = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbtransaksidetail_tmp 
                                    WHERE idBarangDetail = '$_GET[id]' 
                                    AND createdBy = '$_SESSION[loginUser]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $sqlDB = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cekDetBarang);
```

this is the part of code where it will insert the new data to MySQL

```
if($sqlDB == TRUE) {
            if (empty($_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'])) {
                $jumlahKgYgDibeli = $sqlDB['jumlahKgYgDibeli'];
                if ($jumlahKgYgDibeli > $assoc['jumlahKg']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbtransaksidetail_tmp SET jumlahKgYgDibeli = jumlahKgYgDibeli + '$_GET[jumlahKgYgInginDibeli]' WHERE idBarangDetail = '$_GET[id]' AND createdBy = '$_SESSION[loginUser]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                } else {
                    flash('example_message', '<p>Jumlah Kg yang Ingin Dibeli tidak Boleh Melebihi Jumlah Max Kg Barang.</p>', 'w3-red');
                }
            } elseif (!empty($_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'])) {
                $jumlahKgYgInginDibeli = $_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'];
                $jumlahKgYgDibeli = $sqlDB['jumlahKgYgDibeli'] + $jumlahKgYgInginDibeli;
                echo $jumlahKgYgDibeli;
                echo $assoc['jumlahKg'];
                if ($jumlahKgYgDibeli < $assoc['jumlahKg']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbtransaksidetail_tmp SET jumlahKgYgDibeli = jumlahKgYgDibeli + '$_GET[jumlahKgYgInginDibeli]' WHERE idBarangDetail = '$_GET[id]' AND createdBy = '$_SESSION[loginUser]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                } else {
                    flash('example_message', '<p>Jumlah Kg yang Ingin Dibeli tidak Boleh Melebihi Jumlah Max Kg Barang.</p>', 'w3-red');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!empty($_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'])) {
                if($_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'] != $assoc['KgPerBarang']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbtransaksidetail_tmp (idTransaksiDetailtmp,
                                                                idBarangDetail,
                                                                jumlahKgYgDibeli,
                                                                hargaPerKg,
                                                                diskon,
                                                                createdBy,
                                                                dateCreated,
                                                                timestmp)
                                                        VALUES('$idTransaksiDetailtmp',
                                                                '$_GET[id]',
                                                                '$_GET[jumlahKgYgInginDibeli]',
                                                                '$b[hargaPerKg]',
                                                                '$disc',
                                                                '$_SESSION[loginUser]',
                                                                '$tgl',
                                                                '$timestmp')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                } elseif ($_GET['jumlahKgYgInginDibeli'] == $assoc['KgPerBarang']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbtransaksidetail_tmp (idTransaksiDetailtmp,
                                                                idBarangDetail,
                                                                jumlahKgYgDibeli,
                                                                hargaPerBarang,
                                                                diskon,
                                                                createdBy,
                                                                dateCreated,
                                                                timestmp)
                                                        VALUES('$idTransaksiDetailtmp',
                                                                '$_GET[id]',
                                                                '$_GET[jumlahKgYgInginDibeli]',
                                                                '$b[hargaPerBarang]',
                                                                '$disc',
                                                                '$_SESSION[loginUser]',
                                                                '$tgl',
                                                                '$timestmp')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                }

            } else {
                if ($assoc['jumlahKg'] == $assoc['KgPerBarang']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbtransaksidetail_tmp (idTransaksiDetailtmp,
                                                                idBarangDetail,
                                                                jumlahKgYgDibeli,
                                                                hargaPerBarang,
                                                                diskon,
                                                                createdBy,
                                                                dateCreated,
                                                                timestmp)
                                                        VALUES('$idTransaksiDetailtmp',
                                                                '$_GET[id]',
                                                                '$assoc[jumlahKg]',
                                                                '$b[hargaPerBarang]',
                                                                '$disc',
                                                                '$_SESSION[loginUser]',
                                                                '$tgl',
                                                                '$timestmp')") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
                } elseif ($assoc['jumlahKg'] != $assoc['KgPerBarang']) {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbtransaksidetail_tmp (idTransaksiDetailtmp,
                                                                idBarangDetail,
                                                                jumlahKgYgDibeli,
                                                                hargaPerKg,
                                                                diskon,
                                                                createdBy,
                                                                dateCreated,
                                                                timestmp)
                                                        VALUES('$idTransaksiDetailtmp',
                                                                '$_GET[id]',
                                                                '$assoc[jumlahKg]',
                                                                '$b[hargaPerKg]',
                                                                '$disc',
                                                                '$_SESSION[loginUser]',
                                                                '$tgl',
                                                                '$timestmp')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                }
            }
        }
        header("location:../../../med.php?mod=penjualan");

    }
    else
    {
        echo"Tidak ada barang!";
    }

}
```

I use noTransaksiDetail() function I use this code:

```
function noTransaksiDetail()
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(RIGHT(idTransaksiDetail,5)) AS notrans FROM tbtransaksidetail WHERE dateCreated = '".date('Y-m-d')."'");
    $m = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $no = 0;
    if($m['notrans'] <> NULL)
    {
        $kd = number_format($m['notrans'],0) + 1;
        if(strlen($kd) == 1)
        {
            $no = "BDTD".date('dmy')."0000".$kd;
        }
        elseif (strlen($kd) == 2) {
            $no = "BDTD".date('dmy')."000".$kd;
        }
        elseif (strlen($kd) == 3) {
            $no = "BDTD".date('dmy')."00".$kd;
        }
        elseif (strlen($kd) == 4) {
            $no = "BDTD".date('dmy')."0".$kd;
        }
        else {
            $no = "BDTD".date('dmy').$kd;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $no = "BDTD".date('dmy')."00001";
    }

    return $no;
}
```

can someone please help me? thank you so much

can someone please help me regarding this case? Thank you so much

Comment: your pasting in a fairly huge code block. try editing in some comments or break it up a bit smaller to make it easier to read through for better answers.

Comment: okay then wait a bit

Comment: *insert mandatory SQL injection comment*

Comment: ^^ Here you go.. :-) You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! _Never_ trust user data...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm sorry. I changed the title.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand but for now I want to be able to solve this problem using the current code I have. it keeps adding different data with the same ID no matter what I do I'm actually stuck right now.

Comment: Isn't it better to write the code _securely_ and _correct_ from the start? Seems pointless and a waste of time to debug insecure code that will need to be rewritten anyway. Rewriting it might actually solve your issue (or introduce other bugs).

Comment: yeah you got the point here. but this curiosity I have just won't fade away. I just want to know the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, and I don't have time to go over SQL best practices, but the bug is looks like it is caused by a typo in `$timestmp = date('Y-m-d H:i');` I think you mean `$timestmp = date('Y-m-d');`

In your function, you are looking for a timestamp at `date('Y-m-d');`

Either way, I'd check the return value from `SELECT MAX(RIGHT(idTransaksiDetail,5)) AS notransπ…` I suspect that is where you are having your problem.

Comment: select the return value seems to doing fine. it's just when I clicked "add" button, it will keep sending me the same ID. does that mean the function doesn't check if there's the same ID already or is it because the page doesn't get submitted with new one?

Comment: That means `idTransaksiDetail` is being set to the same value each time. This means that the SQL command is returning NULL. No other possible cause, really.